# MySql: will it deadlock on to many insert - Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I wanna migrate from sqlite3 to MySQL in Django. Now I have been working in Oracle, MS Server and I know that I can make Exception to try over and over again until it is done... However this is insert in a same table where the data must be INSERTED right away because users will not be happy for waiting their turn on INSERT on the same table.

So I was wondering, will the deadlock happen on table if to many users make insert in same time and what should I do to bypass that, so that users don't sense it?

Comment: well lock can happen sometimes when one thread want to make insert in same time when another thread is doing insert. Lets say I have experience in those locks in MS Server since i know to have 20 threads inserting web data. I'm not sure that that is timeout.

Comment: I am not sure but I think atomic transaction would work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get deadlock just from rapid insertions. Deadlock occurs when you have two processes that are each waiting for the other one to do something before they can make the change that the other one is waiting for. If two processes are just inserting, the database will simply process them in the order that they're received, there's no dependency between them.

If you're using InnoDB, it uses row-level locking. So unless two inserts both try to insert the same unique key, they shouldn't even lock each other out, they can be done concurrently.

Comment: Yeah table lock happens when you do select and then insert  my bad. However this InnoDB seems great workaround so I google it and found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-locking.html So basically all I have to do is alter tables to engine InnoDB and thats it. Tnx!